# Laravel - Plantillas blade obtener la respuesta del POST

Tags: php, laravel-5

tengo una plantilla en blade que es un formulario de creación de usuario que hace una llamada a una función de un controlador que realiza la inserción del usuario en la BD .

Este controlador tiene un código como este (el código funciona y el usuario se inserta en la BD)

```
    /**
 * Parses, validate and create a new resource.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function storeUser(Request $request)
{
    $roles = Input::get('roles');

    $validator = app('validator')->make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'bail|required|string',
        'email' => 'bail|required|string',
        'status'=> 'bail|boolean',
        'created_at' => 'bail|datetime',
        'created_by' => 'bail|integer',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->jsonValidatorFailedResponse($validator->errors());
    };


    $userCreated = User::create($data->toArray());

    return $this->jsonCreatedResponse($userCreated);

}
```

Luego tengo la plantilla que es el formulario desde donde el usuario introduce los datos que es como esta

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', trans('messages.User Create'))

@section('content')
    <div id="semester-create" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="section-title" class="h2">{{ trans('messages.User Create') }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-3">
                <div id="section-body">
                    <form id="section-form" action="{{ route('admin.users.store') }}" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="identifier">@lang('messages.name') *</label>
                                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" aria-describedby="name_help" data-validation="required" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label for="qr_code">@lang('messages.email')</label>
                                <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="email_help" data-validation="required" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label for="enabled_check">¿Activar usuario?</label>
                                <div id="enabled_check" class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="status" class="form-check-input" name="status" value="1" aria-describedby="status_help">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="enabled">@lang('messages.Enabled')</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="@lang('messages.Save')"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Lo que hace es mostrar un formulario donde el usuario introduce los datos y hace una llamada a la función que he puesto anteriormente.

La función anterior devuelve un JSON porque la idea es poder reutilizar ese método en otras plantillas , entonces mi pregunta es desde esta plantilla como puedo hacer que al hacer el POST haga la acción y capture la respuesta de la función y pueda mostrar algo por pantalla o redigir.

Gracias

Comment: No me queda totalmente claro lo que tratas de explicar, pero sobreentiendo que lo que buscas es AJAX, es decir enviar el formulario sin recargar la pagina y hacer algo en funcion de la respuesta del servidor. Puedes aclarar un poco mas tu pregunta? Tambien te invitaria a revisar [ask] y ha hacer el [tour]. Un saludo y bienvenido a SOes.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estás retornando la data como `JSON` en lugar de una vista. Esto es útil cuando se usa Laravel como backend ofreciendo servicios para realizar acciones en el servidor de modo que el frontend puede hacer consultas HTTP sin estado.

En el modo que estás trabajando veo que estás usando Laravel para back (lógica de negocio) y también para el frontend por lo que lo usual es que las vistas se rendericen desde el servidor (retornar vistas en lugar de data - `json`, `xml`) entonces para solucionar lo que dices puedes hacerlo de dos modos distintos:

## Solución A

Mantener tu modo de trabajo pero retornarnando vistas desde el controlador en lugar de data.

```php
/**
 * Parses, validate and create a new resource.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function storeUser(Request $request)
{
    $roles = Input::get('roles');

    $validator = app('validator')->make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'bail|required|string',
        'email' => 'bail|required|string',
        'status'=> 'bail|boolean',
        'created_at' => 'bail|datetime',
        'created_by' => 'bail|integer',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->jsonValidatorFailedResponse($validator->errors());
    };

    $userCreated = User::create($data->toArray());

    return $this->view('nombre_de_tu_view')->withUser($userCreated);
    // de este modo puedes utilizar el usuario creado en tu vista desde
    // la variable $user
}
```

Esto no cumple del todo lo que esperas hacer: reutilizar el método para otras vistas. Entonces la estrategia que puedes tomar es crear una clase que gestione esta lógica (como un repositorio o trait) de modo que desde los métodos de tus controladores solo invocas a esa clase para la creación de usuarios, devolviendo la data que desees junto con las vistas que quieras.

### Solución B

Realizar las consultar hacia tu servidor desde el frontend a través de llamadas HTTP sin estado por medio de una librería como [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

De este modo tus controladores solo devuelven la data que estás retornando actualmente (`$userCreated`) hacia cualquier vista de tu frontend cuando tú lo desees. Acá te dejo una [guía](https://medium.com/js-dojo/the-ultimate-vue-js-laravel-crud-tutorial-3640baf7eda0) que te dará una pauta más detallada.

Answer (score -1):

En tu función coloca un `dd($request);`

el dd lo que hace es mostrarte lo que estas enviando por parametro.

luego si quieres retornar esto simplemente debes utilizar

```
return redirect('/url')->with('variable_en_vista', $request);
```

espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: Es de muy mala práctica retornar el `$request` a la vista pues puede contener información importante que puede ser mal utilizada para un ataque. Sin contar el hecho de que devuelves más información de la necesaria aumentando el peso del retorno (por más pequeño que sea) y ensuciando el código para futuros colaboradores de desarrollo.

Comment: Hola HCK.  Tienes razón lo considerare para futuros desarollos y respuestas en la web.
Muchas gracias